# R multiple integrals

Tags: r

I have a four integrals like this:

[image]

To calculate this function, my R code is as follows:

```
tol <- 1e-05
t.cutoff = 1e-15

integrand <- function(kappa, sigma, eta, tau) sqrt((tau-eta)/(sigma-kappa))*exp(-(sigma-kappa))

integrate1 <- function(sigma, eta, tau) integrate(integrand, tol * sigma, (1 - tol) * sigma, sigma = sigma, eta = eta, tau = tau)$value
integrate1.vec <- function(sigma, eta, tau) mapply(integrate1, sigma, eta, tau)

integrate2 <- function(eta, tau) integrate(integrate1.vec, tol * eta, (1 - tol) * eta, eta = eta, tau = tau)$value
integrate2.vec <- function(eta, tau) mapply(integrate2, eta, tau)

integrate3 <- function(tau) integrate(integrate2.vec, tol * tau, (1 - tol) * tau, tau = tau)$value
integrate3.vec <- function(tau) mapply(integrate3, tau)


c_t <- function(t) ifelse(t > t.cutoff, integrate(integrate3.vec, tol * t, (1 - tol) * t)$value, 0)

c_t(1)
```

I think my above code is low efficient; I wonder if there is any improvement or available package for this kind of integrals. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm more worried that you do not calculate an error estimate for your final value. It's easy to get this very wrong if you estimate four nested integrals numerically.

Comment: There may be some error due to the numerical integrals. Do you have any suggestion on the integrals? @Roland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This domain of integration can be obtained by applying `cumsum` to a simplex. Thus you can use the `SimplicialCubature` package.

```
library(SimplicialCubature)
integrand <- function(y){
  x <- cumsum(y)
  sqrt((x[4]-x[3])/(x[2]-x[1]))*exp(-(x[2]-x[1]))
}
t <- 1
S <- t*CanonicalSimplex(4)
adaptIntegrateSimplex(integrand, S, maxEvals = 100000L, absError = 1e-4)
```

Result:

```
> adaptIntegrateSimplex(integrand, S, maxEvals = 100000L, absError = 1e-4)
$integral
[1] 0.05961484

$estAbsError
[1] 9.991182e-05
```

I've checked with Mathematica and it gives `0.0596353`.

We get closer to this result by reducing `absError`, but this requires to increase `maxEvals`:

```
> adaptIntegrateSimplex(integrand, S, maxEvals = 1000000L, absError = 1e-5)
$integral
[1] 0.05963446

$estAbsError
[1] 9.993167e-06
```